# How can I extend AppCompatActivity to centralize codes, e.g. DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, drawerlayout, appcompatactivity

I would like to extend `AppCompatActivity` to centralize codes in order to share codes, e.g. `DrawerLayout`, etc.

However, I encounter `NullPointerException`. Here is my code:

**MasterActivity**

```
public class MasterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "MasterActivity";
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected void setupDrawer() {
        // Drawer
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }
}
```

**ChildActivity**

```
public class ChildActivity extends MasterActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);
        setupDrawer();
    }
}
```

**activity_child.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ChildActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- Main Content -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llv_left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#888" >

        <!-- Drawer Content -->

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The NPE appears at:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
```

the error message is:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(int, int)' on a null object reference

Obviously the variable `mDrawerLayout` is null, as `findViewById()` cannot locate it from layout XML. The `R.id.drawer_layout` is located at `R.layout.activity_child`. If the `ChildActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity`, the NPE does not appear.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you post `activity_child.xml`?

Comment: Added into the question, thanks

Comment: If `MasterActivity` is meant to host the `DrawerLayout` and provide it to its subclasses, you should be setting the content `View`, and setting up the `DrawerLayout` in `MasterActivity`. In your subclasses, after the `super` call in `onCreate()`, inflate your subclass's `View` into the main content `LinearLayout`.

Comment: who is FavoriteActivity in xml?

Comment: @someUser typo, forget to change to ChildActivity, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
 protected void setupDrawer(View v) {
   mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   ...
```

and then in `ChildActivity`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);
setupDrawer(findViewById(android.R.id.content));//use root view
```

Comment: what is the difference between this solution & the inflate solution suggested by Mike in above comment? which performs better?